# How to send the content inside divs with display: table-cell to the top of they container?

Tags: html, css

I want to position the content of these two divs to the top.

**HTML**

```
<div class="menu">
    <div></div>
</div>

<div class="content">
    <h1>SDFSDFSD SDFSD</h1>
    <h1>SDFSDFSD SDFSD</h1>
    <h1>SDFSDFSD SDFSD</h1>
</div>
```

**css**
.

```
menu {
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 20%;
}

.menu > div {
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: red;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.content {
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: blue;
    width: 80%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/99u4vm3g/

I tried with vertical-align: top and with position: absolute and top:0 with no luck.

What should I do to send those content to the top of their containers?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you tried to give `vertical-align: top;` to the `.menu` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You added `vertical-align:top` to the wrong place, it should be applied to the `table-cell` elements.

**Updated:** http://jsfiddle.net/tfqmwko1/

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the `vertical-align` on the table-cell elements

```
.menu {
    vertical-align: top;
}

.content {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/99u4vm3g/1/

You are going to see the text still not at the top and that is due to the margin on the header elements

This one has no margin on the header tags http://jsfiddle.net/99u4vm3g/2/